# Application on Bluemix using RapidApps

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have developed application in bluemix using RapidApps and I was able to deploy it successfully on bluemix. I am not able to open that application in web browser. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Can you provide more details on your problem?

Comment: whats the error you are getting,need more details to sort out the issue

Comment: Are you still having this issue?  If so can you please post more information on the issue you are having?

Answer (score 0):

To deploy your app to the Bluemix site to use in a web browser, tablet, or mobile device.
1.  Go to the RapidApps Dashboard, and select your  app
2.  Click the Deployment tab.
3.  Change the name of the URL for the app to whatever host name yoou choose, any unique hostname in the Bluemix domain namespace. Do not use spaces or special characters in the host name.
4.  Click Deploy application.
5.  When the app is deployed, you can click the link to view your application and can share the link for others to start using the deployed instance of the app in Bluemix
Note: In RapidApps, you can preview and test your apps on a real device using the real device option in the application preview. A test app for running any app you create with RapidApps is available to install from the Apple App Store or the Google Play Store.   A QR Code linking to your app gets generated that your device can scan to view your app in your mobile device
Note: Once the app is deployed, you can also download the complete source files for the app, or jump right into the docs and guides for building a native mobile app from the RapidApps version you just created.